# C# Парсинг через System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Match

Tags: c#, html, регулярные-выражения, парсер

Ребят, такой вопрос...
Нужно из этого

```
 <span class="actual_persona_name">THISTEXT</span>
```

парсить THISTEXT, как это можно сделать через

```
String Rate = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Match
```

При том что в THISTEXT могу быть любые символы

Заранее благодарю!

Comment: В чем ваш вопрос? Что не получается?

Answer (score 0):

Можно попробывать что-то типа этого:

```
Regex.Replace(str, @"</?span( [^>]*|/)?>", String.Empty);
```